# Cloudflare content in <head>..</head> element

Tags: jquery, cloudflare

Can someone explain to me the hows and whys about the content cloudflare seems to inject into documents that i create, that are being served through a domain running via cloudflare?

I know how my html looks like, i have built it after all. If i check it via ftp everything looks the same, but if i load it in the browser and inspect the code there is some additional code present. Why is it there for?

All i can see is that it somehow breaks jquery and the page is not working as it should.

Comment: The how is easy, they're hosting your site, they can transmit any content they want.  The why is probably for analytics.  Have you investigated into the content that cloudflare is providing?

Answer (score 0):

I use cloudflare for a high-traffic site and it's helped immensely. cloudflare basically intercepts the request and caches it, then adds some of its own code for other purposes - including caching and tracking (i believe).

i haven't looked in the cloudflare CP for quite some time, but i think there's an option to revome some (or all) of that additional code.

if i remember correctly they have a section on their site that explains that additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Some optional features and apps you will turn on do add code to the site so they can work.

If jQuery is breaking, however, my first guess would be Rocket Loader is potentially breaking it. Do you have this feature turned on in your performance settings? Does it work properly if you turn off Rocket Loader, if on?